# Convert HWND to LPWSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd, lpwstr

I have the following code:

```
MessageBox(NULL, NULL, (LPCWSTR)FindWindow(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad"), MB_OK);
```

How can i make the messagebox's title be the Window Handle to notepad? Is there any effiecient and simple way to do this using c++?

Comment: You could treat it as a number.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  HWND's represent handles to Windows, not strings.  Do you want to parent the MessageBox to Notepad?  Or do you want the title of your MessageBox to be the same as Notepad's title?

Comment: What would you expect to be written in the title? Give an example because the question is unclear.

Comment: The title of the messagebox do i want to be the handle, for example the title is "0x8893"